# Unable to start service Intent, U=0: not found

Tags: android, service, ipc, messenger

I have been struggling for two days on this issue.
I have two apps and trying to communicate by Messenger IPC but it even't failed to bind to server app's service.

--- server side

```
    <service android:name="com.example.RemoteService" android:exported="true">
    </service>
</application>
```

-- client side

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             :
     this.connection = new RemoteServiceConnection();

@Override
public void onStart() {
           :
     Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("com.example.client", "com.example.RemoteService");
    //Intent i = new Intent("com.example.RemoteService");
    //i.setPackage(this.getPackageName());
    boolean ret = bindService(intent , this.connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

> ret is always false and always receives system message 
>   W/ActivityManagerService: Unable to start service Intent {
>   act=com.example.RemoteService pkg=com.example.client } U=0: not found

It seems everything ok for implementation. I feel like it's under layer issue. Please help.

Thanks

Here's Service Class

```
public class RemoteService extends Service
{
    private Messenger messenger; //receives remote invocations
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        if(this.messenger == null)
        {
            synchronized(RemoteService.class)
            {
                if(this.messenger == null)
                {
                    this.messenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());
                }
            }
        }
        //Return the proper IBinder instance
        return this.messenger.getBinder();
    }

    private class IncomingHandler extends Handler
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            System.out.println("*****************************************");
            System.out.println("Remote Service successfully invoked!!!!!!");
            System.out.println("*****************************************");

            int what = msg.what;

            Toast.makeText(RemoteService.this.getApplicationContext(), "Remote Service invoked-("+what+")", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //Setup the reply message
            Message message = Message.obtain(null, 2, 0, 0);
            try
            {
                //make the RPC invocation
                Messenger replyTo = msg.replyTo;
                replyTo.send(message);
            }
            catch(RemoteException rme)
            {
                //Show an Error Message
                Toast.makeText(RemoteService.this, "Invocation Failed!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your package definition correct? If your Service is in package `com.example.client` it should be `com.example.client.RemoteService` (similarly if your Service is defined withinin the package `com.example`, the package and Service strings should be `com.example` and `com.example.RemoteService`)

Answer (score 4):

After recent changes,
You can use `\<queries> \<package android:name ="your package name" /> \</queries>`

https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring

Answer (score 3):

try to start your service like this

```
startService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));
```

don't forget to add your service in your manifest,

```
<application>

    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
         >
    </service>

</application>
```

Comment: It still has error "W/ActivityManagerService: Unable to start service Intent { act=com.example.RemoteService pkg=com.example.client } U=0: not found"

Answer (score 1):

`setClassName` takes the package name and class name as the parameters:

```
intent.setClassName("com.example.client", "com.example.RemoteService");
```

If you package name is com.example.client then class name should be either `RemoteService` or `com.example.client.RemoteService`

Also you can check if the package appears under:
/data/data/com.example....

This error occurs only because the package/class is not found

Answer (score -4):

Some times, if you can not find any wrong in code, you could try reboot device. May be resolve this problem.